# How to count subdirectories in a directory in UNIX?

Tags: directory

I have to count the total number of directories that are in the given directory (note that these are subdirectories).

I know how to count for files but am having trouble counting the directories for my script.

Comment: `find <DirName> -type d | wc -l` . this would include the current directory as well.

Comment: Directories just in the current directory, or directories in _and below_ the current directory?

Comment: Just in the directory (not including the current working directory) I used the above format and then just subtracted 1

Answer (score 5):

In a slightly robuster variation of @rahul's comment:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -printf '1'  | wc -c
```

will print '1' for each directory in the current one that is not the current one (`-mindepth 1`), and then we count the 1s. This will cope with directory names that contain newlines.

Answer (score 4):

If you put a `/` at the end of a wildcard pattern, the pattern will only match directories and symbolic links to directories. The following snippet therefore counts directories and symbolic links in the current directory.

```
set -- */ .*/
if ! [ -e "$1" ]; then shift; fi # handle the case when */ matches nothing
echo $(($# - 2)) # -2 for . and ..
```

In bash, you can simplify this to

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
dirs=(*/)
echo ${#dirs[@]}
```

If you don't want to include directories, use `find`. If none of the directories have a name that contains a newline, you can count the lines:

```
find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune | wc -l
```

To be fully robust, count slashes instead.

```
find . -name . -o -type d -print -prune | tr -dc / | wc -c
```

Answer (score 3):

Counting directories in (only) the current directory:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

Counting directories in the current directory and in all subdirectories contained within it:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```